# DropDown Option Items as one item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have an object with arrays and I would like to put every atribut from 1 array into 1 dropdownlist item.
Currenty i have all attributs from arrays in 1 list item :(

```
let optionItems = this.state.subsystems.map((subsystem, i) =>
<option key={subsystem["a:Name"]}>{subsystem["a:Name"]}</option>

);
<div>
    <select>
        <option>{optionItems}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Thanks for help guys.
Using NodeJs react

Comment: You don't need the option as you've already rendered it
<select>
     {optionItems}
</select>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nesting your `option` tag. Just use:

```
<select>
  {optionItems}
</select>
```